# Having trouble getting anything back but what the default constructor is giving

Tags: c#, class, methods, constructor

I feel like I am getting close using the debugger but am still not able to figure this one out.

I am walking through the following code

```
namespace Taxes
{

public class Rates
{


    //A class constructor that assigns default values 
    public Rates()
    {
        incLimit = 30000;
        lowTaxRate = .15;
        highTaxRate = .28;
    }
    //A class constructor that takes three parameters to assign input values for limit, low rate and high rate.
    public Rates(int lim, double low, double high)
    {
        incLimit = lim;
        lowTaxRate = low;
        highTaxRate = high;
    }
    //  A CalculateTax method that takes an income parameter and computes the tax as follows:
    public int CalculateTax(int income)
    {
        //determine if the income is above or below the limit and calculate the tax owed based on the correct rate
        int taxOwed;

        if (income < incLimit)
            taxOwed = Convert.ToInt32(income * lowTaxRate); 
        else 
            taxOwed = Convert.ToInt32(income * highTaxRate);

        return taxOwed;
    }


} 

// The Taxpayer class is a comparable class
public class Taxpayer : IComparable
{
    //Use get and set accessors.

    private int taxOwed;

    string SSN
    { set; get; }
    int grossIncome
    { set; get; }
    int TaxOwed {
        get
        {
            return taxOwed;
        }
    }

    int IComparable.CompareTo(Object o)
    {
        int returnVal;
        Taxpayer temp = (Taxpayer)o;
        if (this.taxOwed > temp.taxOwed)
            returnVal = 1;
        else if (this.taxOwed < temp.taxOwed)
            returnVal = -1;
        else returnVal = 0;

        return returnVal;

    }  

    public static Rates GetRates()
    {
        //  Local method data members for income limit, low rate and high rate.
        int incLimit;
        double lowRate;
        double highRate;
        string userInput;
        //Rates myRates = new Rates(incLimit, lowRate, highRate);
        //Rates rates = new Rates();

        //  Prompt the user to enter a selection for either default settings or user input of settings.
        Console.Write("Would you like the default values (D) or would you like to enter the values (E)?:  ");

        // if they want the default values or enter their own
        userInput = (Console.ReadLine());
        if (userInput == "D" || userInput == "d")
        {
            Rates myRates = new Rates();
            return myRates;
            //Rates.Rates();
            //rates.CalculateTax(incLimit);
        }

        else if (userInput == "E" || userInput == "e")
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the income limit: ");
            incLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please enter the low rate: ");
            lowRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please enter the high rate: ");
            highRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            Rates myRates = new Rates(incLimit, lowRate, highRate);
            return myRates;
            //rates.CalculateTax(incLimit);
        }
        else return null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Taxpayer[] taxArray = new Taxpayer[5];

        //Rates taxRates = new Rates();
        //  Implement a for-loop that will prompt the user to enter the Social Security Number and gross income.
        for (int x = 0; x < taxArray.Length; ++x)
        {
            taxArray[x] = new Taxpayer();
            Console.Write("Please enter the Social Security Number for taxpayer {0}:  ", x + 1);
            taxArray[x].SSN = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Please enter the gross income for taxpayer {0}:  ", x + 1);
            taxArray[x].grossIncome = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //taxArray[x].taxOwed = taxRates.CalculateTax(taxArray[x].grossIncome);

        }

        Rates myRate = Taxpayer.GetRates();
        //Taxpayer.GetRates();

        //  Implement a for-loop that will display each object as formatted taxpayer SSN, income and calculated tax.
        for (int i = 0; i < taxArray.Length; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taxpayer # {0} SSN: {1}, Income is {2:c}, Tax is {3:c}", i + 1, taxArray[i].SSN, taxArray[i].grossIncome, myRate.CalculateTax(taxArray[i].grossIncome));//taxArray[i].taxOwed);

        } 
        //  Implement a for-loop that will sort the five objects in order by the amount of tax owed 
        Array.Sort(taxArray);
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted by tax owed");
        for (int i = 0; i < taxArray.Length; ++i)
        {
            //double taxes = myTax.CalculateTax(taxArray[i].grossIncome);
            Console.WriteLine("Taxpayer # {0} SSN: {1}, Income is {2:c}, Tax is {3:c}", i + 1, taxArray[i].SSN, taxArray[i].grossIncome, myRate.CalculateTax(taxArray[i].grossIncome));

        }
    }  

} 

}
```

I have everything solved except that the sort is not sorting by the tax owed amount for some reason now.

Comment: Your posted code shouldn't compile, since you have commented out the declaration of `taxRates`, but you still use the (now undeclared) variable in the last Console.WriteLine call.

Comment: @programmerNOOB: You've first asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116706/cant-get-anything-but-0-from-a-call-to-a-method-to-calculate-a-taxamount and then this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117669/having-trouble-with-a-method-call-and-getting-a-correct-value-back and in neither case have you upvoted or accepted an answer. Perhaps you should do that before we finish Assignment5_2 for you?

Comment: @phoog, I know, there has been quite a bit of edits and at the time of copy/paste that wasn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An aside regarding `Taxpayer.GetRates()`: the taxpayer class shouldn't be responsible for determining the tax rates.  If taxpayers could determine tax rates, tax rates would most likely be zero.  It might make more sense to move that into the `Rates` class.

This answer to your question shows an example that should help you understand where you're going wrong.  If you would like a specific suggestion related to your code, please post a complete program that compiles.  The sample code you've posted does not compile (error: "the name 'taxRates' does not exist in the current context").

To answer your question:

> How do I instantiate a class so I can use its methods without calling the default constructor?

As others have noted, you need to *retain a reference to the newly instantiated object, so you can use that instance when you read the values from the fields.*

Consider:

```
void SetRates()
{
    Rates rates = new Rates(10000, 0.3, 0.4);
}

void UseRates(Taxpayer taxpayer)
{
    taxpayer.Tax = new Rates().CalculateTax(taxpayer.Income);
}

void Main()
{
    SetRates();                              // creates an object and throws it away
    Taxpayer taxpayer = new Taxpayer(20000);
    UseRates(taxpayer);                      // creates a new object with default values
    Console.WriteLine(taxpayer.Tax);
}
```

Instead, return the object you created in SetRates() (and call it GetRates() instead).  Then pass it into the UseRates method:

```
Rates GetRates()
{
    return new Rates(10000, 0.3, 0.4);
}

void UseRates(Taxpayer taxpayer, Rates rates)
{
    taxpayer.Tax = rates.CalculateTax(taxpayer.Income);
}

void Main()
{
    Rates rates = GetRates();
    Taxpayer taxpayer = new Taxpayer(20000);
    UseRates(taxpayer, rates);
    Console.WriteLine(taxpayer.Tax);
}
```

With regard to your edited code, you have

```
Rates myTax = new Rates();
Taxpayer.GetRates();
```

Now `Taxpayer.GetRates()` assigns some values to a Rates instance, but *it's not the same Rates instance you created with the statement `Rates myTax = new Rates()`.*  The statement `Rates myTax = new Rates()` *calls the default Rates constructor, and that's the instance that you use later in the method for calculating the tax!*  This explains why your tax is always calculated with the default values.

The GetRates method operates on a *different instance of the Rates class*.  That different instance is created by one of the `new Rates(...` expressions in the body of the GetRates method.  That instance has the rates you want to use, but it is basically trapped inside the method.  Why is it trapped?  Because you only assign the instance to a local variable, and local variables are not accessible outside the method in which they are declared.

It's a bit like this: instead of `Rates`, we have `Car`, and instead of `GetRates` we have `FillFuelTank`.  Your code is then doing the following:

```
Get a new car          //Rates myTax = new Rates();
Go to the gas station  //Taxpayer.GetRates();
```

Now, the GetRates() method ... I mean, the FillFuelTank method ... does this:

```
Get a new car with fuel in it //Rates myRates = new Rates(incLimit, lowRate, highRate)
```

You see what you've done?  You've driven to the gas station in your new car, got a *second car* with fuel in it, and then you *went back to the first car* and drove away -- without putting any fuel into it.

One solution to that would be to pass `myTax` as an argument to the `GetRates()` method; a better solution would be to return a Rates instance from the `GetRates()` method.

You wrote:

> My need for Rates myTax = new Rates(); in main is so that I can call the calculateTax method to do just that. If there is another way to call that method without calling the default constructor, I am all ears or fingers.

The expression `new Rates()` calls the default constructor.  So, the way to call `calculateTax` without calling the default constructor is to call the parameterized constructor instead:

```
Rates rates = new Rates(limit, lowRate, highRate);
double tax = rates.CalculateTax(taxpayer.Income);
```

You might say, "but I did call the parameterized constructor in the GetRates method!"  And there's the problem, again, of filling the wrong car with fuel, because the Rates object in the GetRates method *is a different object*.  You call the parameterized constructor on the object you don't use, and you call the default constructor on the object you do use.

Comment: Wow, I guess that is over my head right now.  I am suppose to get those methods in their specified classes, probably to make it harder I guess.   My main problem is no matter what I choose in the getRates method, I always end up with the defaults constructors values.

Comment: @programmerNOOB take each of these examples and step through them in the debugger.  That should make things clearer.  And post a working sample of your code so we can explain what's happening in it.  The code you posted will not run.  Also, since this is homework, tag it as such and post the assignment, so we don't suggest things that don't satisfy the requirements.

Comment: I have updated the code and will run and also added more info, I think my problem is when the getRates() method is called, the constructor myRates shows up with the values I don't want (default)

Comment: @programmerNOOB I added a discussion of your edited code, and why you get the default values when you calculate the tax.

Comment: thanks that helps to understand what I did a bit.  Now I will research how to return a instance from a method.  The part I don't understand is that another method call to the Rates class method from within getRates().   My need for Rates myTax = new Rates(); in main is so that I can call the calculateTax method to do just that.  If there is another way to call that method without calling the default constructor, I am all ears or fingers.

Comment: @programmerNOOB yes, there's a way to call the method without calling the default constructor.  Please see the edited answer for a discussion.

Comment: thanks I got the constructor working now.  Now my sort is broke and have to fix that.  I have updated the code too

Comment: You're welcome. Sorting is another matter entirely. It's probably better to ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

When the curly brace is reached, the myRates object goes out of scope and ceases to exist.  Your values are coming from somewhere else.

```
   Rates myRates = new Rates(incLimit, lowRate, highRate);
    //rates.CalculateTax(incLimit);
}
```

Comment: so should I instantiate it outside of the method and then call it like myRates.Rates(incLimit, lowRate, highRate); from within the method?

Answer (score 0):

I *think your problem is this line:

```
Taxpayer.GetRates();
```

This is a static method which means it won't set any class member variables.  I'd expect the GetRates() to return a Rates object.