# adding 2 decimal places to Convert.ToString

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wanting my label to show what the total price of a product is after discount. My label does show the total price after the discount but I can't figure out how to add 2 decimal places to the final price. For example if the total price after a discount is $90 I would like my label to show $90.00. I can only figure out how to display the price without decimals.

```
lblTotalPrice.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(totalPrice);
```

Comment: I couldn't find the question from searching. Sorry for creating a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lblTotalPrice.Text = "$" + totalPrice.ToString("0.##");
```

Comment: Flat out wrong answer instead of closing as duplicate...

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @Cory note that this answer neither does what you asked ( try `1f.ToString("0.##")`) nor shows correct way to format currency - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464496/format-decimal-value-to-currency-with-2-decimal-places

Comment: I changed ## to 00 and it worked.

Comment: After reading the link you provided I found the correct solution. Thank you Alexei.

Comment: The question is about `Convert.ToString()` not `object.ToString()`.