# C# nested if/else in a for loop

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

I have a nested if/else statement in a for loop to determine whether or a a value is valid with an array value. It returns all values just fine, however if the IF is correct, it still does the else an additional three times.  I thought once it was equal one time, it would stop, but I suppose I am missing something here.

```
string sectionChoice;
int ticketQuantity;
double ticketPrice, totalCost;
string[] section = { "orchestra", "mezzanine", "balcony", "general" };
double[] price = { 125.25, 62.00, 35.75, 55.50 };
bool isValidSection = false;

sectionChoice = GetSection();
ticketQuantity = GetQuantity();

for (int x = 0; x < section.Length; ++x)
{
    if (sectionChoice == section[x])
    {
        isValidSection = true;
        ticketPrice = price[x];

        totalCost = CalcTicketCost(ticketPrice, ticketQuantity);
        Console.Write("\n\nTotal cost for the tickets are: {0:c2}", totalCost);
    }
    else
        Console.Write("\n\nInvalid entry, {0} does not exist", sectionChoice);
}
```

When it is valid, it returns something like this:

> Your price is 32.50. Invalid entry, x does not exist Invalid entry, x does not exist Invalid entry, x does not exist

Comment: You should be using `decimal` for currency values ([read more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/693372/188246)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is `break;`

`break` will stop the execution of the loop it is inside. If you are inside nested loops it will only work on the innermost.

The opposite of this is `continue`. `Continue` stops that iteration and moves onto the next.

[Here is an MSDN article explaining it more in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)

```
for (int x = 0; x < section.Length; ++x)
{
   if (sectionChoice == section[x])
   {
      isValidSection = true;
      ticketPrice = price[x];

      totalCost = CalcTicketCost(ticketPrice, ticketQuantity);
      Console.Write("\n\nTotal cost for the tickets are: {0:c2}", totalCost);
      break;
   }
   else
     Console.Write("\n\nInvalid entry, {0} does not exsist", sectionChoice);
 }
```

Comment: @JeffreyDilley please don't forget to select this as an answer by clicking the checkmark if this worked for you.

Comment: Absolutely. It says I have to wait a few minutes, but I most certainly will.

Comment: You still might get the invalid entry message several times, if the selected section is not the first!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the question was how to break a loop. Not to fix the logic behind it. Let him learn it through trial and error.

Answer (score 4):

What you're really trying to do is determine if `section` contains a particular value, and do something if it does.  Just check *that* directly:

```
if (section.Contains(sectionChoice))
```

You also shouldn't be using [parallel arrays](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/).  Rather than having two arrays, sections an prices, in which the object at the index of each both "combine" to equal a value, it appears that what you're actually modeling is a means to lookup the price of a particular section.  This is best modeled with a `Dictionary` that can easily look up the value for a particular key.  Here your key is the section, and the value is its price.

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> ticketsPrices = new Dictionary<string, decimal>()
{
    {"orchestra", 125.25m},
    //...
};
bool isValidSection = false;

string sectionChoice = GetSection();
int ticketQuantity = GetQuantity();

if (ticketsPrices.ContainsKey(sectionChoice))
{
    isValidSection = true;
    decimal ticketPrice = ticketsPrices[sectionChoice];

    decimal totalCost = CalcTicketCost(ticketPrice, ticketQuantity);
    Console.Write("\n\nTotal cost for the tickets are: {0:c2}", totalCost);
}
else
    Console.Write("\n\nInvalid entry, {0} does not exsist", sectionChoice);
```

Comment: This answer surpasses the others by identifying the intent and solving the problem a better way.

Comment: What happens with `x`? You still need the index to get the price, but this is the right idea (or a dictionary could be used with Dictionary<string, decimal>)

Comment: @DavidSherret, good point.  Didn't see that initially.  Could be solved by using `Array.IndexOf` and would still be cleaner than the other answers.

Comment: @DavidSherret yeah, the design was even more flawed than I noticed at first glance.  This is why you avoid parallel arrays; it creates a giant mess.

Comment: @adv12 The solution is to get rid of the parallel arrays, rather than trying to work around them.  They'll only continue to act up down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Get the index of the chosen item like this:

```
int i = section.IndexOf(sectionChoice);
if (i >= 0) {
    ticketPrice = price[i];
} else {
    // Not found!
}
```

However your code would become more flexible with an item class

```
public class Section
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

With this class you can create a list of sections like this

```
List<Item> sections = new List<item> {
    new Section { Name = "orchestra", Price = 125.25 },
    new Section { Name = "mezzanine", Price = 62.00 },
    ...
};
```

Now you can find a section like this:

```
Section section = sections.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == sectionChoice);
if (section != null ) ...
```

Like this it is easier to add new properties to the sections. E.g. you could add a number of remaining seats to it, without having to create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want iteration to stop when the `if` condition is met, you need to break out of the loop with a `break` statement:

```
for (int x = 0; x < section.Length; ++x)
{

    if (sectionChoice == section[x])
    {
        isValidSection = true;
        ticketPrice = price[x];

        totalCost = CalcTicketCost(ticketPrice, ticketQuantity);
        Console.Write("\n\nTotal cost for the tickets are: {0:c2}", totalCost);
        break;  // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT CHANGE
    }

}
if (!isValidSection) // TEST MOVED OUTSIDE OF LOOP
{
    Console.Write("\n\nInvalid entry, {0} does not exsist", sectionChoice);
}
```

Comment: You still might get the invalid entry message several times, if the selected section is not the first!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to report that it's an invalid choice for each one that it doesn't match:

```
for (int x = 0; x < section.Length; ++x)
{
    if (sectionChoice == section[x])
    {
        isValidSection = true;
        ticketPrice = price[x];

        totalCost = CalcTicketCost(ticketPrice, ticketQuantity);
        Console.Write("\n\nTotal cost for the tickets are: {0:c2}", totalCost);
        break;
     }
}

if (!isValidSection)
    Console.Write("\n\nInvalid entry, {0} does not exist", sectionChoice);
```

Comment: Could I request a reason for the down votes? This is only my third post. I'm not sure where it's lacking.

Comment: In fact, the invalid entry message must be placed **after** the loop, otherwise it still might be written to the console several times!