# Not expected output in string formatter c#

Tags: c#, string, formatter

So I am working on a project for myself.

Now I am using `string.formatter`

```
bon = bon + String.Format("{0,-2} X {1,-10}  {1,5}", hoeveelheid[i], frieten[i], hulp);
```

The problem lays in "hulp" this is a `double`. But it is not showed in the output. instead the same output as frieten[i] is outputted.

Like so :

> 4  X klein       klein

The output needs to be like : `

> 4X klein  €15,00

`

Comment: Index of third parameter is 2 not 1 `{1,5}`

Comment: Beware that monetary calculations should always be done with `decimal`s instead of `double`s.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your `{1,5}` to `{2,5}`.

Also if it is a double value, you *might* need to format it with [The `"C"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString).

You can create own custom `NumberFormatInfo` and format your double as;

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo()
{
     CurrencySymbol = "€",
     CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",",
     CurrencyPositivePattern = 0,
     CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2
};
```

and

```
bon = bon + String.Format("{0,-2} X {1,-10}  {2,5}", 
                          hoeveelheid[i], frieten[i], hulp.ToString("C", nfi));
```

By the way: [What is the best data type to use for money in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/693372/447156)

Comment: @user3574537 Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are repeating your second variable twice:

Change the last format from : `{0,-2} X {1,-10}  {1,5}`
to 
`{0,-2} X {1,-10}  {2,5}`