# C# sum problems

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to get the sum of a column in a data grid view.

```
private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
    }
    try
    {
        decimal tot = 0;
        for (int i=0; i <= dataGridView4.RowCount -1; i++)
        {
            tot += Convert.ToDecimal (dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
        }
        if (tot==0) {}
        textBox34.Text = tot.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I am getting the error message

Input string was not in a correct format.

ِI found that the problem is in the formatting. Becasue the SQL server data type for that column is money. and the SQL server changes any number I save to this format. 00.0000
For example, If I save 10 SQL server saves it as 10.0000

If I remove the (.) I get no errors.

If I try to sum 10.0000 + 3.0000 it never works out.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is displayed the value in your grid column? Do you have your local separator (for example a comma) for decimals or do you have the point as separator?

Comment: Sounds like a locale problem. Do the language configured on your computer use anything else than a `.`  to separate decimals?

Comment: I tried that at many computers, they all use the (.) how to change that to (,)

Comment: @But what language are they configured in?

Comment: Why not sum it as a decimal instead?

Comment: What country are you located in?   Some countries settings use comma instead of period for the decimal place.

Comment: Any suggestions by providing an example is more than appreciated, I am not a professional programmer. I am located in AMMAN - JORDAN

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am saving my data to the Microsoft Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to convert a value with a decimal point from string to int. When using the `money` datatype in your DB, the best datatype to use in your code will be the `decimal` type. See the answer on [What is the best data type to use for money in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693376/5395709)

So doing:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32("10.00");
```

Will yield the following error (which is what you're receiving):

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.

You can convert the value using the `Convert.ToDecimal()` method:

```
decimal val = Convert.ToDecimal("10.00");
```

If you want to remove the decimal portion of the value, you can use one of the following methods based on your requirements:

- [Math.Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Math.Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz5da1c(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Math.Truncate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example:

```
decimal val2 = Math.Round(val);
```

Or:

```
decimal val2 = Math.Truncate(val);
```

If you simply want to return the value as a string but without the decimal portion, you can do as follows:

```
decimal val = Convert.ToDecimal("10.00");
Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("0.#"));
```

Edit:

So in your code, change:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
}
```

For:

```
decimal sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, could you please edit my code and show where to adjust?

Comment: @MicrosiM Updated answer showing what you need to change. Make sure you accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: @MicrosiM Great to hear. Make sure you accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem. Cheers!