# C# What type should I cast here?

Tags: c#, types, nullable

I have a portion of code which calculates a new balance by reading from a database all prior charges and payments and then adding the new amount that's going to be charged to the balance.  It was working fine with values that I'd hand planted into the database, but then I started getting errors when I wiped all the test values and started from scratch.

This is the code:

```
        //sum all prior charges
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Charges WHERE TransactionDate<='" + DateTime.Now + "';";
            chargesSoFar = (double)command.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        // sum all prior payments
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE TransactionDate<='" + DateTime.Now + "';";
            paymentsSoFar = (double)command.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        // calculate balance
        tempCharge.Balance = (decimal)(chargesSoFar + int.Parse(textBoxAmount.Text) - paymentsSoFar);

        DataWriter.WriteCharge(tempCharge);
```

The errors I'm getting are type conversion errors where I cast the ExecuteScalar result.  The error is happening because there are no prior charges or payments, so null is being returned, which fails when casting to double.

Is there another type I can cast to, which I can then check if it's null? If not, how do I get around this?

Any help is appreciated.  Please ask any questions if I haven't been clear in what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Check out nullable types like `double?` or `Nullable<double>`

Comment: Why don't you first check for null, then cast to the appropriate type? Or use nullable types?

Comment: Mitya, Thank-you. That is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: L-Four. There is no way of checking if it's null before executing the query.

Comment: "when casting to double" - You are not using `double` for monetary amounts, are you? I see you use the double value in calculation and then cast the result to `decimal`. So you seem to be partly aware of the drawbacks. Why not make that consistent?

Comment: it returns an object which can be null. And I did not mean before executing, i meant after executing of course, then casting. using a nullable is the same.

Comment: `if (!double.TryParse(command.ExecuteScalar(), out chargesSoFar) changesSoFar = 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try nullable datatype:

```
double? chargesSoFar = null;
// other codes here
chargesSoFar = (double?)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

As a sidenote, a parameterized query is most likely the best practice to prevent sql injection. To do this,

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;

    command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE TransactionDate <= @TransData;";
    command.Parameter.AddWithValue("TransData", DateTime.Now);
    chargesSoFar = (double?)command.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

According to this question: [What is the best data type to use for money in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693372/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-c)

The best data type to use is decimal.

```
decimal? chargesSoFar = null;
// other codes here
chargesSoFar = (decimal?)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: While it's not really contributing to a solution to the problem, I'd recommend to _not_ use `double` for monetary amounts.

Comment: Thanks. That was something I have on my to do list for when I have the basic functionality working.

Comment: @Fildor definitely agree.

Comment: I did originally have it as a decimal.  I changed it to double when I first though that was the problem.  I will change it back to decimal.

Comment: I still get a "Specified cast is not valid" error even when using  `decimal?` as the type. I don't know what else could be causing the error.

Comment: how about changing to `chargesSoFar = command.ExecuteScalar() as decimal?;` or `chargesSoFar = Convert.ToDecimal(command.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: @LennyLen it should have corresponding type in your database too (like `decimal` or `money`). If it's still `float` in your database - `ExecuteScalar` will return double, which cannot be casted to .NET decimal.

Comment: John Woo: using `chargesSoFar = command.ExecuteScalar() as decimal?;` worked.   Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to a nullable type by using a question mark suffix, i.e. (double?), then you can check for null.

```
     paymentsSoFar = (double?)command.ExecuteScalar()
     if (paymentSoFar.HasValue){
```

**Please** also read up on SQL Injection: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/ as your code is currently vulnerable to this type of attack

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can cast to `Nullable<double>` i.e `double?`

```
double? paymentsSoFar = (double?)command.ExecuteScalar();

if(paymentsSoFar.HasValue)
{
    // Then its safe to calculate 

    double myActualValue = paymentsSoFar.Value;
}
```

---

[Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

> **Nullable types have the following characteristics:**
>
> - Nullable types represent value-type variables that can be assigned the value of `null`. You cannot create a nullable type based on a
>     reference type.
> - The syntax `T?` is shorthand for `Nullable<T>`, where `T` is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable.
> - Assign a value to a nullable type just as you would for an ordinary value type, for example `int? x = 10;` or `double? d = 4.108`. A nullable
>     type can also be assigned the value null: `int? x = null`.
> - Use the `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault` method to return either the assigned value, or the default value for the underlying type if the
>     value is null, for example `int j = x.GetValueOrDefault();`
> - Use the HasValue and Value read-only properties to test for `null` and retrieve the value, as shown in the following example:
>     `if(x.HasValue) j = x.Value`;
> - The HasValue property returns true if the variable contains a value, or `false` if it is `null`.
> - The Value property returns a value if one is assigned. Otherwise, a `System.InvalidOperationException` is thrown.
> - The default value for HasValue is `false`. The Value property has no default value.
> - You can also use the `==` and `!=` operators with a nullable type, as shown in the following example: `if (x != null) y = x;`
> - Use the `??` operator to assign a default value that will be applied when a nullable type whose current value is null is assigned to a
>     non-nullable type, for example `int? x = null; int y = x ?? -1;`
> - Nested nullable types are not allowed. The following line will not compile: `Nullable<Nullable<int>> n;`

Comment: @RufusL this was a fire and forget question, Thanks for the heads up