# I need a alternative to using a field initialize in a struct C# (Cannot have instance field initializers in structs)

Tags: c#

Basically, I understand why I am getting an error here, however, I am not entirely sure what I should do as an alternative, here is my code:

```
public struct CashAmount
{
    public int leftNumberExact, decimalNumberExact;

    public string CashAmountExact = leftNumberExact + "." + decimalNumberExact;

    public float CashAmountApprox = float.Parese(CashAmountExact);
}
```

Basically, I am trying to make a datatype that has exact precision like an int, but also has decimals. It must be absolutely EXACT no matter what which is why I am not using a ulong or double or some other form of floating point precision.

Comment: use `decimal` then

Comment: Unless you want `CashAmountExact` to always return `0.0`, you should be defining a *property*, not a *field*. Since what you've tried to do would only be evaluated *once* during construction. In turn, `CashAmountApprox` would also be, but I'm worried about what you're trying to do here giving the mashing together of types.

Comment: I never knew ulong was a floating point type. And based on the [language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/floating-point-types-table) it isn't....

Comment: I think you might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693372/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-c

Comment: You need to learn more abou types. Exact presicion but also decimal is vahue. All types have a relative presicion. PI is endless in presicion, i do not believe you want that.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want. You still need to initialize `'leftNumberExact'` and `'decimalNumberExact'`, but the other properties will Work:

```
public struct CashAmount
{
    public int leftNumberExact, decimalNumberExact;

    public string CashAmountExact
    {
         get:
         {
             return leftNumberExact + "." + decimalNumberExact;
         }
    }

    public decimal CashAmountApprox
    {
        get:
        {
            return decimal.Parse(CashAmountExact);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have made the fields into properties with only a getter.

I have also changed to the `'decimal'` type, which should be total accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If the constraint is actually "must be absolutely EXACT no matter what" then you should use something that enforces these constraints, for example peteroupc's [Numbers](https://github.com/peteroupc/Numbers) library on github.

See the [EDecimal class](https://peteroupc.github.io/Numbers/docs/PeterO.Numbers.EDecimal.html) which enforces this rule for division:

> Returns NaN if the result can't be exact because it would have a nonterminating decimal expansion.

This means, for instance, that 1/3 == NaN:

```
EDecimal.One.Divide(3) == NaN
```

In general, I think this is overly restrictive, and you're probably better off using a sane and intuitive library like a wrapper for [GMPLib](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gnumpnet) (the GNU multi precision library), or any number of other libraries available: [one](https://github.com/tompazourek/Rationals) [two](https://github.com/danm-de/Fractions).

If you're set on implementing something yourself, then at least check out the other libraries because you're going to end up with something similar to or based on [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2).