# Storage options for Loops? C#

Tags: c#, loops

Hello i am learning programming and trying to create a simple console app for users to buy movie tickets.

i am currently using a lot of loops and i would like to know if there is a way to:

1:Store user input from the loops.

2:take stored data from the loops and add it into a final tally.

I have tried Using an Array to store user inputs from the loop but when i want to take the data to be then stored in a final tally i get a error: Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'int[]' and 'int'.

I do not want to post my full source but hopfully seeing my vairables should help you understand what i need to track.

Thank you in advanced, any help is welcome.

```
            //Ticket sale math Values
            double TotalIncome;
            double IncomeFromChild;
            double IncomeFromAdult;
            double IncomeFromStudent;
            double VATFinal;

            //Tickets Sold (name of film or total)
            double FilmA = 33;
            double FilmB = 15;

            double TotalTicketsSold;
            float PeopleServed;

            //Ticket Sale Counters
            double ChildTickets = 0;
            double Adulttickets = 0;
            double StudentTickets = 0;


            //Array For Ticket prices, sales and user input
            var TicketChoices = new int[3];

            var TicketAmount = new int[48];

            //Maxxium tickets allowed for each film
            int FilmA = 33;
            int FilmB = 15;
            int TotalTickets = 48;
```

Comment: This message ' Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'int[]' and 'int'' actually means you're trying to do some sort of arithmetic operation, say an addition, between an array of int and an int which makes no sense. When you're manipulating the array, if let's say you want to add 5 to every value it contains, you need to loop within the array and add 5 to every value contained in it.

Comment: Also, the variables `FilmA` and `FilmB` are each declared twice. How does this compile? Anyway, I suggest that you a) Tell us **exactly** what the program needs to do; and b) Give us **all** of your code. This doesn't seem like a large program, we can take it.

Comment: See also [Best Data Type to Use for Currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693372/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-c) --things that should be `decimal` are set to `double` (there's rounding difference with the two) , and things that would do better as `int` are set to `double`. Why use `float` instead of `int` for a single whole-number?

Comment: You need to post a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); the code you posted doesn't show the error you are talking about, has other errors you don't mention, and includes [too much irrelevant code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect a bunch of *something*, a good first step is to create a class or struct.

Here's a basic idea - I'm not going to get into best practices or anything:

```
public class UserInput
{
    public decimal IncomeFromChild { get; set; }
    public decimal IncomeFromAdult { get; set; }
    public decimal IncomeFromStudent { get; set; }        
    public decimal TotalIncome => IncomeFromChild + IncomeFromAdult + IncomeFromStudent;
}
```

As you receive each set of values, you can create an instance of `UserInput`.

```
var myInput = new UserInput {IncomeFromChild = 5.00M, IncomeFromAdult = 3.5M};
```

That makes the original question much easier to answer. How do we store these? When we want to store some of something, we use a [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/selecting-a-collection-class).

Perhaps the most commonly used collection is a `List`, because you can just add stuff to it.

Add the import `using System.Collections.Generic;` to the top of your file first.

```
var myListOfInputs = new List<UserInput>();
myListOfInputs.Add(myInput);
```

Then you can look at all the items in the list like this:

```
decimal total = 0M;
foreach(var input in myListOfInputs)
{
    total = total + input.TotalIncome;
}
```

There are also a lot of extension methods for performing operations on collections. If you add this import to the beginning of a file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

You can use this:

```
var total = myListOfInputs.Sum(i => i.TotalIncome);
```

It's essentially the same as the loop above, just shorter to write. It doesn't hurt to learn by writing some things like that out the long way.