# double value changing once stored in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I have the following code that converts my satoshi value to a bitcoin value:

```java
private static double satToBtc(long sat){
        return sat / Math.pow(10, 8);
    }
```

now I have the following code executing:

```java
            double btc = satToBtc(value);
            User user = User.getUserByDepositBitcoinAddress(address);
            if (user == null) return;
            try (Connection connection = MySQL.getConnection();
                 ...
 
                statement.setDouble(3, btc);
                ...

                return;
            }
```

now what is happening is, I am given the satoshi amount of 100,000 which is worth 0.001 (the function returns exactly `0.001`) bitcoin but when I store it in my mysql table it sets the value as: `0.00000001`.

How do I go about fixing this?

EDIT - UPDATED `satToBtc` function:

```java
    private static BigDecimal satToBtc(long sat){
        return new BigDecimal(sat / Math.pow(10, 8));
    }
```

Comment: "the function returns exactly 0.001" - no it doesn't. It *can't*, because the value 0.001 can't be represented exactly in a `double`. I suspect you'd be better off using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Oh, okay one moment let me give it a shot.

Comment: And what mysql table column type are you using? This should be `decimal` also.

Comment: @JonSkeet what would be the SQL datatype for bigdecimal? I tried the Decimal data type but it just returned `0`, when I run the satToBtc function with a value of `100000` using big decimal it returns: `0.001`, so it works, but i just don't know the mysql datatype.

Comment: @Progman in all honesty, that just confused me.

Comment: @JonSkeet it actually returned `0.001000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375`, so you where right about that, now its  just the SQL issue.

Comment: It sounds like you need to go off and do some research about using BigDecimal with MySQL - you can do that *entirely separately* from this code. Just create a table with a single column, and write a tiny console app that just inserts a hard-coded BigDecimal into it. Once you've got *that* working, you can come back to this.

Comment: By 'sql issue' I mean the fact its not storing properly.

Comment: @Loran Save the value as satoshi and convert it only when displaying it to the user. That way you don't have to do floating math operations, which can be tricky.

Comment: @Progman you're the smartest man alive.

Comment: @Loran See other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693372/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-c on how to work with money values.

Comment: THIS ISSUE HAS BEEN FIXED THANKS TO @Progman (and Jon Skeet), thanks for your help guys.